# Why intent.getExtras().mMap is null when I debug?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-bundle

I have a BroadCastReceiver like this:

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(intent.getExtras().keySet().toArray()));

    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.angryyogurt.yotransfer">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"/>


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name=".NewIncomingReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action
                android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"
                android:priority="1010"/>
            <action
                android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL"
                android:priority="1010"/>
            <action
                android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"
                android:priority="1010"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

</application>

</manifest>
```

I use this to listen to the SMS. When I try to send message to this phone, it prints the key set `[format, pdus, slot, phone, subscription]`.

But when I debug it and set the breakpoint at `System.out.println...`, I see that `intent.mExtras.mMap` is null. Why is this? How to check items of the map in intent during debugging?

Comment: post your menifest please

Comment: @DavidJhons I added AndroidManifest.xml file above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The instance variable `mMap` is only populated after the extras are unmarshalled (unparceled, deserialized). If you haven't done anything to cause the extras to be unmarshalled, `mMap` will be `null`.

Try this:

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        boolean b = intent.hasExtra("blah");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(
                intent.getExtras().keySet().toArray()));
    }
}
```

calling `hasExtra()` will force the extras `Bundle` to be unmarshalled. Set your breakpoint on the `System.out.println()` and you should see the extras in `mMap`.